# statistics test for heteroscedastic and homoscedastic data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, variance, heteroscedasticity

Which statistics tests should be applied on heteroscedastic and homoscedastic data, respectively? What are the differences?

Comment: This seems like a very broad question - there are thousands of hypotheses tests. What kinds of hypothesis are you testing?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are interested in knowing how you should test for if your data is heterocedastic or not, right?

In this case, the two most common tests are:
- [the Breusch-Pagan test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test)
- [the White test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_test)

Check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22196/on-testing-for-heteroskedascity-some-questions-on-the-white-test-breusch-paga) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47490/breusch-pagan-test-for-heteroscedasticity-contradicts-whites-test) questions to get some insight about there differences.